# How to compute explicitly the inverse of $L+I$ where $L$ is the Laplacian of an undirected graph and $I$ is the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

How to compute explicitly the inverse of $L+I$ where $L$ is the Laplacian of an undirected graph and $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: Is there a reason that you think there's a nice "formula" here?

Comment: I don't know, I hope that. $L$ contains only integers (in addition, -1 in the off diagonal).

Comment: I guess it never hurts to hope; I doubt it though.  It's also good to note that $L$ is positive definite and that $L + I$ is diagonally dominant, but I don't see that bringing us closer to the answer on its own.

Comment: You can find $L + \alpha I$ with a "geometric series" if $\alpha>0$ is big enough, but that also doesn't seem like it will help.

Comment: Can I use any tool to reduce computation time in calculating inverse?

Comment: It might be helpful to use the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).  Or, if your matrix is sparse, there are tools out there to handle that efficiently.

Comment: @TobiR , if you don't mind my asking, why are you trying to compute the inverse of $L+I$? If you are trying to solve a system of linear equations of the form $(L + I)x=b$ then there are nearly linear time solvers you could use.

Comment: $L+I$ is the coefficient matrix of an OLS estimation of large sample (m~250,000) and variable number (n~100,000), whose inverse will obtain the variances and the covariances of the fitted parameters, therefore I would like to determine its inverse. If you know O(n) solver, I could use O(n^2) inversion, if I solve the (L+I)*(L+I)^-1=I equation. So, may you tell me more about this solver?